# how can i delete my hard drive and format to NTFS

Tags: permanent-delete

How can I format my disk to NTFS
I need to delete everything so I can buy Windows XP and reinstall
thanks
Barara

Comment: You can not buy Windows XP anymore.

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu installed now?  In any case, if you install a version of Windows, there will be an option to format the disk.  See for example "Do I need to format my hard disk before installing Windows 7" ( http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/installing-windows-7-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: the windows installer will format automatically. from linux gparted or mkfs.ntfs

Answer (score 0):

Check the installation of `ntfs-3g`

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Open a terminal and identify your drive:

```
lsblk
```

Sample output:

```
sdc      8:32   1   7,5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   7,5G  0 part /media/user/BAFC-91D9
```

Then unmount the device

```
sudo umount /dev/<your_device_and_partition>
```

in my case

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc1
```

and format with

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/<your_device_and_partition>
```

in my case

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1
```

---

*Or simply install Windows. The hard disk is automatically formatted.*